# How to test if a user is in a site context in Alfresco Share?

Tags: alfresco-share

I need to test if a user is within a site context or not to perform some action in share page views. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I need to move the global search bar to the collaboration navigation section in all sites but leave it where it is if the user is not in a site. To do this I was hoping to detect whenever a user is within a site context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up duplicating the search bar in the collaboration-navigation bar and with a sprinkle of javascripting, able to hide and display the Global search bar, when in sites.